# How to get a quick idea on Generics?

Tags: generics

How to get a quick idea on Generics ? 
Sugesst me some good book/web-site...

Comment: Are you looking for a tutorial in a specific language, or a more abstract overview?

Answer (score 1):

These guys might know something about it

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf